# Bivariate moment generating function

Tags: moment-generating-functions, bivariate-distributions

For two random variables $(X,Y)$, the MGF can be defined as $M_{XY}(s,t) = E[e^{sX+tY}]$.

Find $M_{XY}(s,t)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are two jointly normal random variables with $E[X] = μ_X,E[Y] = μ_Y ,Var(X) = σ_X^2 ,Var(Y) = σ_Y^2 ,ρ(X,Y) = ρ.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $Z=Y-cX$. Choose $c$ such that $EZX-EZEX=0$.  We now have independence of $X$ and $Z$ since jointly normal variables are independent iff their covariance is $0$. Now $Ee^{sX+tY}=Ee^{(s+ct)X+tZ}=Ee^{(s+ct)X} Ee^{tZ}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $X, Y$ are normal random variables, then

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{c}
  X\\
  Y
\end{array}
\right] \sim
 \mathcal{N} (\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  \mu_1\\
  \mu_2
\end{array}
\right],
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  \sigma^2_X & \rho\sigma_Y\sigma_X\\
   \rho\sigma_Y\sigma_X & \sigma^2_Y
\end{array}
\right])
 $$

If $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is the covariance matrix and $\mathbf{X}$ the column vector of the random variables,  the probability density function will be:

$$f(\mathbf{X}) =\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{\mu})^T\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}}(\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{\mu})}}{2\pi|\mathbf{\Sigma}|^\frac{1}{2}}$$

We also know that

$$E[e^{sX + tY}] = \iint f_{X, Y}(s, t)e^{sx + ty}dxdy$$

From then on, it's just a matter of calculations.